# Receiving TypeError when trying to viz crosstab in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, seaborn

I'm trying to create a basic bar chart from a cross tab.

I wrote:

```
# Crosstab: Impact YN x Engagement
impact_action_table_eng = 
pd.crosstab(df.Engagement,df.impact_action_yn_new)
print(impact_action_table_eng)

impact_action_yn_new    0    1
Engagement                    
0                     566  310
0                       1    1
1                     676  410
2                       0    1
2a                    508  404
2b                    587  303
3                     683  671
4                     172  357
5                      31  237
```

And then want to visualize it.

```
# Crosstab: Impact YN x Engagement - Viz

stacked_imp_eng = impact_action_table_eng.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})
sns.barplot(x=stacked_imp_eng.Engagement, y=stacked_imp_eng.impact_action_yn_new, hue=stacked_imp_eng.impact_action_yn_new)
```

I'm getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: str and int. I think that means the data type needs to be changed, but I'm not sure if which... or if that is the right change (I've tried changing to several data types and still getting the type error).

Impact_action_yn_new is a int64 and eng is a str. I then converted impact_action_yn_new to a str and that hasn't solved teh problem.

What do I need to do here? I've been googling and am stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both both `y` and `hue` set to the same column, `impact_action_yn_new`. This might be the source of the error, though I can't reproduce it using Seaborn 0.9.0. In any case, having `y` equal to `hue` is probably not that useful!

Using `y='value'` and `hue='impact_action_yn_new'` gives the following:

```
sns.barplot(x=stacked_imp_eng.Engagement, 
            y=stacked_imp_eng.value,
            hue=stacked_imp_eng.impact_action_yn_new)
```

[image: barplot result]

Comment: @AlissaSwartz, great to hear and happy coding!